# How to delete entity (sql tables) using doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

while creating the database schema with doctrine I used "quantité" as a name for a field, because of the "é" which is a special character I'm facing a lot of problem while adding items to the database, I tried to edit the name in the php file of the entity and I changed the "é" by "y" after that I couldn't update the schema or doing something else withe doctrine, the following error appear every time:

```
In RuntimeReflectionService.php line 63:

  Property App\Entity\Produit::$quantité does not exist
```

What could I do to edit the name of the field and update my database? or how could I do to delete all the table that contain the "quantité" field and update my database?

Comment: Just rename the column on your DB, no need to do it "through doctrine".